# Gender is enum with FEMALE, MALE

Tags: java, enums, java.util.scanner

So then when we use class with main method, how do we go about it in this case?

For example:

```
System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
String name = sc.next();
```

But the question if gender is of type Gender, how would we apply it then in same situation with a scanner?

Would it start something like this:

```
Gender gender = sc.
```

Question is what comes next after sc.

As well as let's say we created an object

```
Employee employee = new Employee (gender);
```

And then gender in brackets comes underlined red as I can't figure out how to apply type Gender in scanner after sc.

Answer (score 1):

## Use `Gender.valueOf(sc.next())`

Since `Gender` is an `enum`, the method `static Gender valueOf(String)` is automatically created.

You just use it like this:

```
String femaleString = "FEMALE";
Gender femaleGender = Gender.valueOf(femaleString);

String maleString = "MALE";
Gender maleGender = Gender.valueOf(maleString);
```

Of course, you might want to elaborate your input and allow lowercase input and/or just `M` or `F`. So you might want such a converter:

```
enum Gender {
  FEMALE, MALE;

  public static Gender fromString(String str) {
    String normalized = str.toUpperCase();
    return Arrays.stream(Gender.values())
      .filter(g -> g.name().startsWith(normalized))
      .findFirst()
      .orThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No gender starting with " + str));
  }
}
```

And then the usage becomes:

```
Gender gender = Gender.fromString(sc.next());
```

Comment: That's great. Thanx for response. It is above my level a bit but I will definitely try to apply it today. Much appreciated.